# How do I get my wireless USB mouse working

Tags: ubuntu, usb, mouse

My wireless USB mouse is not plugging and playing.

This is my first time using linux (Ubuntu 12.04) and I'm trying to get a development environment going to learn to use the shell, Python, and other things as I learn more.

I have done my best to solve the problem, but I cannot find a solution.
I have run `lsusb`, and I can see the Novatek device goes away when I enter `lsusb` without the usb nub plugged in.

Is there anyway to use my mouse? On windows, it's plug and play. I don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 6):

I'd run `lsusb` with more debugging turned on to see what specifically the Linux system knows about the mouse.

```
$ lsusb -vv
```

Also take a look at the `dmesg` log to see if the mouse was detected correctly and if a driver and/or kernel module was assigned to it during start.

For example in my `dmesg` log for my mouse:

```
$ grep -i mouse /var/log/dmesg
[    1.668480] mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.637695] generic-usb 0003:046D:C521.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input0
```

I can see it was detected and assigned to `input0`.

Another tool that has helped is `hwinfo`, specifically `hwinfo --mouse`. Fr example:

```
$ # hwinfo --mouse
38: USB 00.0: 10503 USB Mouse                                   
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: R8DB.etCFWb3M1lD
  Parent ID: FKGF.0j9+vWlqL56
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 2-1.1:1.0
  Hardware Class: mouse
  Model: "Logitech USB Receiver"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x046d "Logitech, Inc."
  Device: usb 0xc521 "USB Receiver"
  Revision: "57.01"
  Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0028
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse1)
  Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse1, /dev/input/event5, /dev/char/13:69, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-event-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-event-mouse, /dev/char/13:33, /dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-mouse, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-mouse, /dev/char/13:63
  Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:33)
  Speed: 1.5 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v046DpC521d5701dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02"
  Driver Info #0:
    Buttons: 8
    Wheels: 2
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #37 (Hub)
```

The above shows which driver is being used for this device, `usbhid`.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the batteries from the mouse while the USB dongle is plugged in. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Install solaar via synaptic and you should be good to go!

Comment: Could you add a little more explanation, eg what is `solaar` and `synaptic`

Comment: `synaptic` is the package manager of Ubuntu. _Solaar is a Linux device manager for Logitech’s Unifying Receiver peripherals_ (quoted from [here](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/)).

Comment: Solaar is only for logitech. Doesn't work for other mouses.

Answer (score 0):

Mice, even wireless USB ones, are rather standard pieces of hardware (unless you are talking about some top-of-the-line gamer mouse, or one of the contraptions with a half dozen buttons). I suspect your mouse (or perhaps the USB receiver, or even the USB port) are just broken. If it is some type of non-standard mouse, it *might* be that the mouse is just somehow misconfigured (buttons reassigned or some such mess). But in that case, the only way to fix it is probably via the "driver" under Windows.

Try the mouse on another machine; try another mouse on this machine, plug the mouse into another USB port. Try e.g. a pendrive to check if USB is even working.